# In auctex, to insert citation, how to display all the search results

Tags: auctex

In emacs, auctex, when I use `C-c [`, I only get a list of my previous searches
[image]

When I start typing a search term such as sengul, it highlights my previous search sengul2013 and when I press return, I only get the result sengul2013 and I can not choose another citation which has the search term sengul in it. I am trying to clear the other entries but could not do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so much about `auctex` as the fact that you are using `ivy` as a completion mechanism.  In yr example, to select the current input rather than any of the choices displayed, hit `C-M-j` which calls `ivy-immediate-done`.

If, like me, you get burned by this often, consider setting `ivy-use-selectable-prompt` to `t`.  Then you can `C-p` onto the input line and just hit return.

Comment: Learned something new. Thanks a lot.